# Difficulties submitting an iPhone app to the iTunes store

Tags: iphone

I get the following error message when I upload my app to the iTunes store:

> Unable to authenticate the package:
>   437087467.itmsp. The file name penny talk+corporate+mobile.app.ZIP in the
>   package contains invalid
>   characters. The valid characters are:
>   A-Z, a_z, 0-9, dash, period

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2):

It says right there that you have invalid characters in the file name. Change the `+`es to `-`es.

Comment: thnx for ur response but i did nt put any special symbols in to my  file name.

Answer (score 1):

The + is a space.
Spaces are not allowed.
Remove these.

Comment: Why would some of the spaces be converted to `+` and others not? If all were converted to `+`, then it would start with `penny+talk`, not `penny talk`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with the + in the file name of the .app file.

Can you change those to underscores?

Answer (score 0):

> The valid characters are: A-Z, a_z, 0-9, dash, period.

`+` and `*` are not allowed.

Comment: @icktoofay. Nope. `-` is a hyphen.

Comment: @TRiG: Technically you're right, but I think by “dash” they really meant `-`. (To be even more pedantic I could point out that `-` is really a hyphen-minus, not *just* a hyphen; `‐` (U+2010) is a hyphen.)